# How can I tell Jenkins I want the last n lines of logs to appear in Standard Error

Tags: jenkins

Currently, from my test execution, I see the first 10 lines of logs if the test has passed. I see the first n lines of logs if the test has failed. Ideally, I would like to see the last 100 lines of logs in Standard Error.

There are no settings setup in my Jenkins file, so I assume the current behavior is the default behavior of test execution. I need a way to change it.

I have tried ${BUILD_LOG, maxLines, escapeHtml} which gets me the logs that can be emailed to someone

I have tried messing around with System Logs

I would like my standard error to show the last n lines of logs

Answer (score 0):

This is probably A way to do it(definitely not THE way or may not be the most efficient way)

1. Once the build completes do a curl to get the console logs, use something like this and store the file in the workspace: `curl -isk -X -H "$CRUMB" $BUILD_URL/consoleText --user "$USER:$APITOKEN" -o consolelogs.txt`
2. Then you can simply tail the file for the last 100 lines. eg: `tail -100 <log file>   > newLogfile`
3. Combine it with [Log parser plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Log+Parser+Plugin) with a known string like `****start of logs****` and create a rule to parse it.

For point #1 refer this for getting the crumb, [Jenkins API access](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API)

Update: 
Just realized that the above approach may be difficult from within the same job, Either a down stream job can used or redirect the entire test logs to a file on the workspace without sending it to stdout and then use the tail and Log parser plugin to achieve the result

Comment: This is really helpful, but I don't want to "get" the logs for some other task.
When a job executes, Jenkins shows StdOut, StdErr. I want to manipulate what is shown there